# How to turn off copy with syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code version 1.10 [Copy with syntax highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_copy-with-syntax-highlighting) has been introduced.

I don't want to use it most of the time but I can't find a way to turn it off.
Even though I have no keybinding set for `editor.action.clipboardCopyWithSyntaxHighlightingAction` VSCode always copies with Syntax highlighting.

How can I turn it off so that I copy plain text only?

Comment: I don't think you can.  From an issues page : "we put both plain text and html in clipboard and it's the target application who decides which format to paste."  So it comes down to how you paste/paste Special etc. that determines whether you get plain text or source formatting.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3518

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to `settings.json` file and add

```
"editor.copyWithSyntaxHighlighting":false
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20837

Comment: This setting does not work as expected. I just tried copying an attribute value from an xml file open in Visual Studio Code. The attribute is styled as bold format and in a blue color. With this setting active, both the bold format and the blue color remains when copying the text to word. When I disable the feature the bold format still remains. That is not the expected behavior.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Indeed, VSCode is different...but this answer gave me what I needed to fix my VSCode frustration, regardless..

Answer (score -1):

Using Visual Studio 2019, go to Tools/Options/Text Editor/Advanced then 'Copy rich text on copy/cut' to save color when cutting code from VS and pasting into Word.